# MySQL Can not open connection after call connection.end() => Error: Pool is closed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, node-mysql2

**config.js**

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'krometal',
    charset: "utf8mb4_bin",
    multipleStatements: true
};
const connection = mysql.createPool(config);

connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    //connecting to database
    if (err) {
        logger.log('error', err);
        console.log("MYSQL CONNECT ERROR: " + err);
    } else {
        logger.log('info', "MYSQL CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY.");
        console.log("MYSQL CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY.");
    }
});

module.exports = {
    connection
}
```

**login.js**

```js
const loginUser = async (req, callback) => {
  connection.query(sql, async function (err, rows) => {
      // logic
      callback(result, 401, connection);
  })
}
```

**route.js**

```js
users.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    await loginUser(req, async (response, code, connection) => {
        await connection.end();
        res.status(code).send(response);
    });
});
```

The problem is the first time I try login worked fine, but if I try the same login API again throw the error `Error: Pool is closed.`

Should I use the

> connection.end()

method every time I open connection or mysql2 automatically end connection?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run

```
await connection.end();
```

After running this function you need to create a new connection using

```
connection.getConnection();
```

Comment: I removed ```await connection.end();``` and everything worked fine, but on large scale, the connection will reach its limit.

Comment: and where exactly should i put ```connection.getConnection();``` and why? i think connection should open once I hit any api

Comment: @HusseinMohamed i think opening a new connection every time a request comes in is not a great idea. Performance would be a big issue.

Comment: @HusseinMohamed The documentation says, that you can use `pool.query` without `pool.getConnection()`. [https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)

Comment: I am using https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2 not https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: It should work anyway, without calling getConnection. Just return the created pool from the config.js file.